# Flutter not compiling error Error: The method 'CustomStyle.copyWith' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'TextStyle.copyWith'

Tags: flutter, dart

When I tray to compile (there are no programming errors in screen) but in compilation show these error logs:

> ```
> */C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/styled_text-3.0.4+1/lib/custom_style.dart:17:13:
> ```
>
> Error: The method 'CustomStyle.apply' has fewer named arguments than
> those of overridden method 'TextStyle.apply'.
> TextStyle apply({
> ^

This is my pubspec.yaml

> name: myprject description: A new Flutter project. publish_to: 'none'
> version: 1.0.0+1 environment:   sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" dependencies:
> flutter:    sdk: flutter   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
> flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1   rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
> connectivity: ^3.0.6   path_provider: ^2.0.6   dio: ^4.0.1
> percent_indicator: ^3.4.0   flutter_archive: ^4.1.0
> flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0   flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
> flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0   flutter_scale_tap: ^1.0.5
> intl: ^0.17.0   shared_preferences: ^2.0.8   flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
> styled_text: ^3.0.4+1   audio_service: ^0.18.1   just_audio: ^0.9.18
> url_launcher: ^6.0.16   permission_handler: ^8.3.0   animations:
> ^2.0.2   transformer_page_view: ^0.1.6   chewie: ^1.2.2
> video_player: ^2.2.7   flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3   vibration:
> ^1.7.4-nullsafety.0   flare_flutter: ^3.0.2   rive: ^0.8.1
> screenshot: ^1.2.3   share_plus: ^3.0.4   external_path: ^1.0.1
> flame: ^1.0.0   flutter_fortune_wheel: ^1.2.0   elliptic_text:
> ^1.0.1+9
>
> dev_dependencies:   flutter_test:
> sdk: flutter   sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
>
> flutter_lints: ^1.0.0   http: ^0.13.3   provider: ^5.0.0
>
> flutter:   uses-material-design: true   assets:
> - assets/   fonts:
>
> ```
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19044.1645], locale es-MX)
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.6)
> [√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> [√] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
> [√] Connected device (6 available)
> [√] HTTP Host Availability
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a mismatch between your Flutter version (which is relatively new) and a (half year) old version of the `styled_text` package. As I understand, there was a change in the function signature of the `copyWith` function in `Style` classes. Simply updating the dependency should work. Replace it in your pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
styled_text: ^5.1.0
```

As a general hint, you can run `flutter pub outdated` to identify packages that can be updated.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you want you can mark my answer as accepted so other people won't open this question thinking it still needs answering